# Meteor / Jasmine / Velocity : how to test a server method requiring logged in user?

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity, meteor-jasmine

Using velocity/jasmine, I'm a bit stuck on how I should test a server-side method requiring that there be a currently logged-in user. Is there a way to make Meteor think a user is logged in via stub/fake ?

```
myServerSideModel.doThisServerSideThing = function(){
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if(!user) throw new Meteor.Error('403', 'not-autorized');
}

Jasmine.onTest(function () {
    describe("doThisServerSideThing", function(){
        it('should only work if user is logged in', function(){
            // this only works on the client :(
            Meteor.loginWithPassword('user','pwd', function(err){
                expect(err).toBeUndefined();

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is add users just to your test suite. You could do this by populating these users in a the *server-side* test script:

Something like:

```
Jasmine.onTest(function () {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (!Meteor.users.findOne({username:'test-user'})) {
       Accounts.createUser
          username: 'test-user'
  ... etc
```

Then, a good strategy could be to use the `beforeAll` in your test to login (this is *client* side):

```
Jasmine.onTest(function() {
  beforeAll(function(done) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword('test-user','pwd', done);
  }
}
```

This is assuming your test isn't logged in yet. You can make this more fancy by checking for `Meteor.user()` and properly logging out in an `afterAll`, etc. Note how you can handily pass the `done` callback to many of the `Accounts` functions.

Essentially, you don't have to mock a user. Just make sure you have the right users, with the correct roles, available in the Velocity/Jasmine DB.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion ! I've created users created in a fixtures file already, but are you saying I can tell Jasmine's server integration tests to wait until the user is logged in ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. The `beforeAll` (and actually all Jasmine subfunctions) accept a `done` callback. Essentially Jasmine will wait until either the done callback is called with or without an error **OR** the timeout is reached.
Since the `login...` (and other) methods have the option to add a callback *and* they hand the callback an error if something goes wrong, you can just plug in the `done` callback.

Comment: Really useful thanks ! Can I ask where you found the documentation for this ?

Comment: Essentially there is no good public documentation. Some guys are working on a book, I guess they'd mention some of this stuff. Once you figure out how to deal with async stuff, it gets a bit more easy to understand. (By the way, if you're still new to this, I'd recommend trying coffeescript for a while. We **love** it.)

Comment: Cheers Thomas ! I've tried coffeescript a few times, never really caught on.... there's already far too much coffee in my life at the moment :)

Comment: Is this solution working with latest versions of meteor and jasmine/velocity?

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have a server side method like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    serverMethod: function(){
        // check if user logged in
        if(!this.userId) throw new Meteor.Error('not-authenticated', 'You must be logged in to do this!')

       // more stuff if user is logged in... 
       // ....
       return 'some result';
    }
});
```

You do not need to make a Meteor.loginWithPassword before executing the method. All you got to do is stub the `this.userId` by changing the `this` context of the method function call.

All defined meteor methods are available on the `Meteor.methodMap` object. So just call the function with a different `this` context

```
describe('Method: serverMethod', function(){
    it('should error if not authenticated', function(){
         var thisContext = {userId: null};
         expect(Meteor.methodMap.serverMethod.call(thisContext).toThrow();
    });

    it('should return a result if authenticated', function(){
         var thisContext = {userId: 1};
         var result = Meteor.methodMap.serverMethod.call(thisContext);
         expect(result).toEqual('some result');
    });

});
```

EDIT: This solution was only tested on Meteor <= 1.0.x

Comment: Meteor.methodMap is undefined for me (Meteor version 1.2.0.2) ?

Comment: Anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing and why does it require a user to be logged in? Most of the methods I have that need a user object I pass the user object into.  This allows me to call from a test without actually being logged in. So in the actual running of the code I would pass...

```
var r = myMethod(Meteor.user());
```

but when running from the test I would call like...

```
it('should be truthy', function () {
  var r = myMethod({_id: '1', username: 'testUser', ...});
  expect(r).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! what i want to test is that this method can only be run when a user is logged in and this user has a certain role (cf. alanning:roles). i have created the user with the necessary role in a fixtures file, but i can't figure out how to test that my method is applying the role check correctly...

Comment: Option 1. Break out your role check and have it unit tested separately, again just by passing in the different scenarios it would need to handle. That way you know that piece works.
Option 2. Use a client integration test so you can get the login, then user Meteor.call("yourMethod") to call your method from the client.

Comment: thanks for the advice... i guess i could take option 1 but it's not very satisfactory. option2 would be fine but it's not a meteor method, rather a private server-only method

Comment: You can just have the meteor method just point to your method. `Meteor.methods({
 clientMethodName: myServerMethod
});` so it can be called by both. I use these so I can unit test my methods but also call from the client via code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `Meteor.server.method_handlers["nameOfMyMethod"]` allows you to call/apply a Meteor method and supply `this` as the first parameter at least in the current version (1.3.3)

```
this.userId = userId;
Meteor.server.method_handlers["cart/addToCart"].apply(this, arguments);
```